# Configurable products and price attribute in layered naviagtion

Tags: configurable-product, layered-navigation, ce-1.9.1.0

I have a **rugs** category in my store and each rug is a configurable product with a base price, and has associated simple products that either add or subtract from the base price depending on the size.

Given that smaller sizes subtract from the base price (so they have a "negative" price) the price attribute in layered navigation only has one option *0.00 and above*, which makes it pointless to have and useless for the customer.

I'm sure others have faced a similar situation -- what is the best way of dealing with this?

How can I have the price attribute in layered nav. use the simple products pricing instead of the config products? Maybe there is an extension that can help?

Comment: 1. Why do you use configurable products instead of simple products with options? and if for some reason you cannot
2. Why don't you use your smallest rug as the base price?

Comment: 1. Because I have a script that happens to make adding configurable products much easier than adding simple products with custom options, so I don't have a choice there unfortunately. 2. I feel like it's misleading to the customer, by using the middle size as the price it appears a little more accurate, since it's kinda an average. I guess this is one option but since I have 1800 rugs with 20,000 associated simple products I would rather find a different solution.

Comment: So I found two paid extensions which solve my problem, here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html & here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-products-use-simple-price.html -- maybe there is another solution or a free extension I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the correct price in layered naviagtion for configurable products is real.

You have to correctly calculate the `min_price` field in `catalog_product_index_price` table.

Calculation takes place at reindex in class: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable`

If my post will score 10 likes - I write the complete code to do it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for another answer :) I've accepted this, hopefully you can continue the code and I'm sure once you do it will earn many up votes over time. I'm about to purchase an extension but I don't think it does what I want.